# How can I get one object data from my Firebase by ref

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get an object from my firebase.

I try to get my Trip object, but I get a null value.

This is my db image

[image: this is my db image]

[image]
[image: data and data guide]

this is my code

```
db_ref = db.getReference("Trips").child(dataguide+" "+data).child(data);

db_ref.child(data).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {        
      trip2 = snapshot.getValue(Trip.class);
   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

so I ask why

Comment: may I know what is the value for the `data` and the `dataguide` ?

Comment: The value of `trip2` is only going to be up to date **inside** `onDataChange()`. If you `System.out.println(trip2.toString());` in there, it might show the value. But definitely: if you `System.out.println(trip2.toString());` **outside** of `onDataChange` there is no guarantee of whether the data has been loaded yet.

Comment: @Zuhrain  yes i attached them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 
`db_ref.child(data).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` 
remove **child(data)** cause you are already inside the child there is no chiled names ...so change the code to this
"data"`db_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()`